# IF statement doesn't go through

Tags: c++, codeblocks

If I type in 3 5 3 1 it doesn't go through the `if` statement, I can't really find why, I thought it should because those number are not equal except 3 and 3.

```
cin>>x1 >> y1>>x2>>y2;
if(x1<=1000000 && x1>0 && x2<=1000000 && x2>0 && y1<=1000000 && y1>0 && 
y1<=1000000 && y1>0){
xp2=x2;
yp2=y2;
xp1=x1;
yp1=y1;
cout<<">>"<<xp1<<" "<<yp1<<endl;
cout<<">>"<<xp2<<" "<<yp2<<endl;
cout<<"----------"<<endl;
//TRIES TO FIND A SUB-TREE AND TELL THE DISTANCE BETWEEN X1,Y1 AND X2,Y2
if(xp1!=xp2 && yp1!=yp2){
while(xp1!=xp2 && yp1!=yp2 || xp1!=yp1){
    xp1=x1;
    yp1=y1;
    a2=0;
    while(xp1!=xp2 && yp1!=yp2 || xp1!=yp1){
        if(xp1<yp1|| xp1!=yp1){
            yp1-=xp1;
            a++;
        }else if(xp1>yp1|| xp1!=yp1){
            xp1-=yp1;
            a++;
        }cout<<">>"<<xp1<<" "<<yp1<<endl;
    }
    if(xp1!=xp2 && yp1!=yp2|| xp1!=yp1){
        if(xp2<yp2|| xp1!=yp1){
            yp2-=xp2;
            a2++;
        }else if(xp2>yp2|| xp1!=yp1){
            xp2-=yp2;
            a2++;
        }cout<<xp2<<" "<<yp2<<"<<"<<endl;
    }
cout<<"LOOP CHECK"<<endl;
}
cout<<"IF CHECK"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius nop i will try i'm quite a newbie in the programming scene

Comment: Please show the declarations of the types, its difficult to give any advice when the types aren't known.

Comment: @SPlatten 'int x1,x2,y1,y2,xp1,xp2,yp1,yp2;
    int a = 0,a2= 0, att=0;'

Comment: @GvidoBērziņš Learning how to use debugger, would save you more time in the long run, due to you not having to wait for someone to tell you why your code isn't doing, what you are expecting. With debugger, you can step through the code line-by-line, while seeing the values of variables, etc., at any step of the execution.

Comment: What system are you working on, are int's 32 bit ?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius that's great advice, didn't know about this feature, thanks!

Comment: out of your problem you test two times `y1<=1000000 && y1>0`, second times must be with y2.

Comment: When you have multiple tests in your while condition or if, use () to make it clearer what you are expecting to see.

Comment: I think these while conditions: "while(xp1!=xp2 && yp1!=yp2 || xp1!=yp1)
    while(xp1!=xp2 && yp1!=yp2 || xp1!=yp1)" should read: "while(xp1!=xp2 && (yp1!=yp2 || xp1!=yp1))
    while(xp1!=xp2 && (yp1!=yp2 || xp1!=yp1))"

Comment: @bruno It wasn't the problem i changed it, thanks for noticing, but it only checks if the input is in the right bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the values `3 5 3 1` the test

> if(xp1!=xp2 && yp1!=yp2){

is false because xp1 and xp2 value 5, so you do nothing

---

And as I said in a remark

```
if(x1<=1000000 && x1>0 && x2<=1000000 && x2>0 && y1<=1000000 && y1>0 &&
   y1<=1000000 && y1>0){
```

must be

```
if(x1<=1000000 && x1>0 && x2<=1000000 && x2>0 && y1<=1000000 && y1>0 &&
   y2<=1000000 && y2>0){`
```

Comment: Oh, if i understand correctly now  it only goes through if both of them are true

Comment: yes `a && b` is true when both _a_ and _b_ are true